# CreateFreshApiToken doesn't create the laravel_token cookie

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

As the title says CreateFreshApiToken doesnt create any cookies. So I cant use it to auth a logged in user for other requests related to the user.

I tried to set a cookie on the response and it works perfectly fine. So this has to do something with CreateFreshApiToken not working.

**AuthController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\User;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function signup(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string'
        ]);
        $user = new User([
            'name' => $request->name,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => bcrypt($request->password)
        ]);
        $user->save();
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Successfully created user!'
        ], 201);
    }

    public function signin(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'email' => 'required|string|email',
            'password' => 'required|string'
        ]);
        $credentials = request(['email', 'password']);

        if(!Auth::attempt($credentials))
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Unauthorized'
            ], 401);

        $user = $request->user();
        $tokenResult = $user->createToken('Personal Access Token');
        $token = $tokenResult->token;
        $token->save();

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Successfully signed in!'
        ]);
    }

    public function signout(Request $request)
    {
        $request->user()->token()->revoke();
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Successfully signed out!'
        ]);
    }

    public function user(Request $request)
    {
        return response()->json($request->user());
    }

    public function test()
    {
        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'test'
        ]);
    }

    public function test2(Request $request)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'laravel_token' => $request->cookie('laravel_token')
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Kernel.php**

```
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
           //...
           \Laravel\Passport\Http\Middleware\CreateFreshApiToken::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
           'throttle:60,1',
           'bindings',
           \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        ],
    ];
```

**api.php**

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'auth'
], function () {
    Route::post('signin', 'AuthController@signin');
    Route::post('signup', 'AuthController@signup');
    Route::get('test', 'AuthController@test');
    Route::get('test2', 'AuthController@test2');

    Route::group([
        'middleware' => ['auth:api']
    ], function() {
        Route::get('signout', 'AuthController@signout');
        Route::get('user', 'AuthController@user');
    });
});
```

And this is my angular code:

```
  test() {
    return this.http.get('http://homestead.test/api/auth/test', {withCredentials: true})
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
      });
  }

  test2() {
    return this.http.get('http://homestead.test/api/auth/test2', {withCredentials: true})
      .subscribe(response => {
        console.log(response);
      });
  }
```

I've also setup cors with https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors successfully with 'supportsCredentials' enabled. I am also sending a useless GET request to see if any laravel_token is set in the cookie but no success.

Answer (score 0):

`CreateFreshApiToken` is part of the `web` middleware group, so in order for it to set cookies you need your login page to be a `web` route (instead of an `api` route).

Comment: Same issue. I get XSRF token and laravel_session but no laravel_token.

Comment: Are you trying to get the laravel_token from your `signin` route or from your `user` route?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this part of the problem by replicating `CreateFreshApiToken::handler` in my login controller:

```
$response = response()->json([], 200);
// ADD THIS LINE:
$response->cookie(\Laravel\Passport\Passport::cookie(),$request->session()->token();
return $response;
```